# Is there any way to see the codes of functions you've typed in your Python CMD

Tags: python

Just found out that when I pressed up in my cmd one of my function codes is no longer accessible meaning I couldn't see the code I made it with. Is there any way I can see it again? And is there any way I could see all the functions I created for this session in Python cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to do something like:

```
import readline
readline.write_history_file("myhistory")
```

in the python shell, where you defined the function.

You can find your function in the "myhistory"-file afterwards.

There exists an `inspect` module with `inspect.getsourcelines`, but that only prints code for functions defined in source-files.

Answer (score 1):

dir() should give you everything.

**EDIT**

```
>>> def blah():
...   return 1
...
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', 'blah']
>>>
>>> dir(blah.func_code)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__
', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr_
_', '__str__', 'co_argcount', 'co_cellvars', 'co_code', 'co_consts', 'co_filenam
e', 'co_firstlineno', 'co_flags', 'co_freevars', 'co_lnotab', 'co_name', 'co_nam
es', 'co_nlocals', 'co_stacksize', 'co_varnames']
>>> blah.func_code.co_code
'd\x01\x00S'
```

Comment: But `dir()` will only give you the *name* of the function, not the implementation. If that is enough, fine :)

Comment: How can I see the codes inside the functions I made? And is there anyway to manipulate them (delete a function for example)

Comment: @Tichodroma fair point. If you're naming your methods correctly (well) it should be obvious.

Comment: Well I want to see the implementation because I forgot to save them in a separate physical file. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can "delete" a function by assigning `None` to it.

**EDIT**

If you want to know what you typed, you should probably put your code inside a file and import or execute it. The buffer of the Python interactive interpreter is limited.